# Why does this toy color mixing cube exhibit asymmetrical behavior?

Tags: optical-materials

I have this "color mixing cube" desk toy; when looked through, each axis filters a different primary  color of light.

It seems to be made of a cube of transparent material (refraction index around 1.6 by eyeball estimation), with six pieces of colored film glued on the sides.

From the direction of one distinguished vertex, it looks like this:

[image: All the visible faces are of their corresponding primary color (top is cyan, front is yellow, side is magenta). When there is a reflection inside the cube, no filtering occurs; for instance enter from cyan bottom, reflect on yellow side then exit from cyan top, the light is pure cyan.]

However, from the exact opposite vertex, it looks like this:

[image: The areas corresponding to light entering and leaving by two opposite faces is still of a pure primary color, but where an inside reflection happens, filtering of the corresponding side color happens; we see the three secondary colors]

It seems to me that, for each pair of opposing faces, the two faces of the pair have different behavior when it comes to internal reflections; one of the faces filters the reflected light, and the other doesn't.

How is this possible? Did they use two different materials for each color pair, or is there another explanation?